# convert video to angular 2 animation

Tags: javascript, angular, animation

Is here a way to convert video file to angular2 animation?
I want to have very very light video like animation on the page
Now i transformed video file to set of pictures and showing hiding images.
I can upload gif animation, but it is too heavy.

Maybe i'm doing smth wrong and there is another, more efficient way for solving such problems?

Comment: Angular animations are like CSS animations, rules to make some object on your web page move, appear , disappear, change color smoothly. It's not about animation like "animated movies" or "animated gifs"

Comment: It might be possible to create an animation being inspired by the animated gif, but as is there should not be a magic tool converting your animated gif to angular animation.

Comment: first of all, you should show the animated gif. Second, your question might be more suited for another SE site.